# Cut page title with Google Analytics filters

Tags: html, regex, seo, google-analytics

Question: I'm trying to use some regex to cut off a section of the page title, so the results in one of my dashboards is less cluttered.  Example:

Page title: Apartment in Sunny Valley(id: 3242) - Real Estate Company

I want to cut it, so it shows like this in the GA widget:

Apartment in Sunny Valley(id: 3242)

What can I do? I tried some regular expressions but I guess are badly written because when it tries to load the widget it gives me the message of "resource not found, try again later".

What do you recommend?

UPDATE: 
I read about it, and gave it a try by splitting the document.title directly and then sending it with GA using

```
_gaq.push(['_set', 'title', 'new title']);
```

I haven't checked if it works yet, but besides hammering it through js, is there a way to do this inside GA?

UPDATE 2:
this last update didn't worked either.  So, I don't know how to get through this; what can I do?  Anybody tried this before?

Answer (score 0):

I've read in a few places you can do this:

```
_gaq.push(["_set", "title", document.title.replace(' - Real Estate Company', '')]);
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);
```

It might be worth testing out though, because the documentation isn't so forthcoming.

Comment: that's a nice idea.  I used the 'split' function in js to cut off the ' - Real Estate Company' and then create a new title with cut_string[0] and send it to the ga function, but this is a lot more clean.  I will try it and see how it goes

Comment: we meet again Mr. Anderson...hehehe. No, really this didn't worked for me; I tried to split the title using the '-' as token but it didn't worked.  What other javascript function I could use for splitting the URL title?